# VB.Net Create linklabel Function

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a function that will create a linklabel programmatically. Is this possible?

In my program, I am creating a main menu that will have specific link labels. When these Linklabels are clicked, it will search my SQL Database table for all controls associated with this linklabel. Then, it will programmatically create all the controls.

My plan was to create a function, that would scroll through the control list, and create all the linklabels. But I cannot even figure out how to create the linklabel as a new linklabel using the variables passed to the function.

```
Function CreateLinkLabel(LinkName As String)
    Dim LinkName As New LinkLabel

End Function
```

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that you have the same name for your LinkLabel as you have for your string parameter.

Comment: I want the linklabel to have the same name as is being passed through the string. That's what the string is for.

Answer (score 0):

To use a label as a button so that when you click on it the following do an action. Got to the label Properties>Events>Action, double Click on Click then Write your codes inside.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAVWA.png)